# Password problem

Tags: password

I instaled Ubuntu from USB, which worked fine.I entered name and password (as was required twice).
Now the combination name-password seems not to work, which means I can't start up again.

What to do?

Regards, Frank

Comment: Have you lost your password? Do you remember your userID?

Comment: If your password had special characters (non alpha numeric) it might be the keyboard layout locale? If it has numbers are you using a keypad or the numbers above QWERTYUIOP? If keypad is number lock on?

Comment: change your password in recovery mode.

Answer (score 2):

1. Restart you machine, go into GRUB menu (hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot if it is needed to show the menu).
2. Select "Advanced options for Ubuntu".
3. Select kernel which has "recovery mode" suffix.
4. Select "root".
5. Press Enter for maintenance
   (or press Control-D to continue):

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   passwd <username>
   ```

   ```
   Enter new UNIX password:
   Retype new UNIX password:
   passwd: password updated successfully
   ```

   ```
   systemctl reboot
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't remember my password. Additionally, I couldn't restart in recovery mode. Shift key didn't work. Actually, I've alredy reinstalled edubuntu. I wrote my password.and keep saved.